# Using 600W load with C2 MCB

Tags: electrical-panel, load

Can I use 600W electric kettle in a circuit which has a MCB rated as C2?

The power supply voltage is 220V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple formula that relates Volts, Watts and Amps.

> W = V * A

You know the watts and the volts, and need to know amps to compare that to your circuit breaker.  Basic algebra tells us that Amps is going to be Watts divided by Voltage.  So, your kettle is going to use

> 600W / 220V = 2.7A (about 3 Amps)

A C2 breaker is rated for 2 Amps, so it would not be sufficient for that kettle.

Answer (score 0):

600 w on 220 v is 2.727 amps your 2 amp breaker would not hold